# Grouping a Python Dataframe containing columns with column locations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe below where i am trying to group each them into a single row by person and purchase id. column purchase date location contains the column name in which the date is located for said purchase. i am trying to use the location to determine the earliest date a purchase was made

| person | purchase_id | purchase_date_location | column_z | column_x | final_pruchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | column_z | NaN | NaN |  |
| a | 1 | column_z | 2022-01-01 | NaN |  |
| a | 1 | column_z | 2022-02-01 | NaN |  |
| b | 2 | column_x | NaN | NaN |  |
| b | 2 | column_x | NaN | 2022-03-03 |  |

i have tried this so far:

```
groupings = {df.purchase_date_location.iloc[0]: 'min'}

df2 = df.groupby('purchase_id', as_index=False).agg(groupings)
```

My problem here is due to the iloc[0] my value will always be column_z, my question is how do i make this value change corresponding to the row and not be fixated on the first

Answer (score 0):

I would try solve it like this:

```
df['purchase_date'] = df[['purchase_date_location']].apply(
                           lambda x: df.loc[x.name, x.iloc[0]], axis=1)
df2 = df.groupby('purchase_id', as_index=False).agg({"purchase_date": min})
```